# Can two Case sobjects have the same child ContentVersion?

Tags: case, contentversion, contentdocument, parent

I am trying to delete a ContentDocument under Case sobject safely. In order to do so I will delete the Case's related ContentVersion's ContentDocument, which will delete the ContentDocument and its ContentVersions. 
Is it safe? Can there be a situation were I delete a ContentDocument that a different Case will be related to as well?

Thanks

Edit:
I managed to create two cases that have DocumentContentLink to the same ContentDocument, by adding the "Files" section to the "Case" Page Layout. Thanks for the answers, they make everything more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can there be a situation were I delete a `ContentDocument` that a different Case will be related to as well?

**Yes**. `ContentDocument` records are connected to the various locations where they have been shared (libraries, record pages, users) by `ContentDocumentLink` records. `ContentDocumentLink` is essentially a junction object between some other record and `ContentDocument`. Then, `ContentVersion` is parented under `ContentDocument`.

In many orgs, files attached to records are *likely* only shared to that record, but the Content system certainly makes it possible for the same file to be shared in more than one location.

Answer (score 0):

> Can there be a situation were I delete a ContentDocument that a different Case will be related to as well?

Yes. Consider this use-case. You have an sobject record and have attached a file choosing from **Salesforce's File storage** instead of uploading from a local computer. Let's say the file's name is sample.pdf

When you open another sobject record and attach the same sample.pdf to this record again by choosing from **Salesforce existing files and not from local system** then it is said to have single content document and version but multiple ContentDocumentLinks(these content document link records will have user who uploaded(linkedEntityId), 1st sobject record(linkedEntityId), 2nd sobject record(linkedEntityId) and a contentDocumentId as parentids.